# Change orientation without reload in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I created layouts in layout-port and layout-land(same names) I want switch land between port layouts when orientation. I use below line in manifest but now it only select correct layout at the beginning. Then it only rotate that layout and layouts don't fit. If i don't use this line, it always calls onCreate method and reload the program.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

If there is no solution, i can do with programming but i need to get active layout. Is there a function like "getContentView"( i know old android versions there is no function like that) ?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - when you rotate, Android will kill the existing Activity and recreate it so it can load the new configuration (different resources given the different screen orientation). Is there a reason you don't want to recreate the Activity?

Answer (score 0):

How did you exactly named your `layout-folders` in your `res-folder`?

Android should choose at runtime the layout for Portrait and for landscape but only if the `Folders` are correctly named. If not, by declaring

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

`onCreate, onPause and onDestroy` are not called but instead `onConfigurationChanged` is called. You can handle everything you want to do programmatically in this method!

See here for more Information:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: I use Android studio, it helps me. If ı don't change orientation of phone, there is no problem. Is there a way to deactive calling onCreate every time?

Comment: @user4385522 With `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` your `onCreate` isn't called at rotating the device!